# Android, как получить название американского штата по своим координатам

Tags: android, google-maps-api, gps, геолокация

Вообщем вопрос,думаю, понятен. Допустим, задача стоит так, я ввожу любые координаты, естественно, связанные с США, и должен получить название штата. Я пробовал поковырять geocoder, но что-то безуспешно. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Что значит "безуспешно"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Штат можно получить, используя `getAdminArea()` у `Address`.

```
public String getState(Context ctx, double lat, double lng) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(ctx, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        return obj.getAdminArea();       
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

P.S. не забываем пермишен

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```